# How to get a json response using Curl from IBM Watson

Tags: php, html, json, curl, watson

I am trying to code a simple web app which calls IBM Watson NLC api to classify the text user will input to a textbox.

I have created the following and it works if single word is input and fails incase a sentence is given. Whats wrong? any help pls.

Input language will be arabic.

### File 1 - NLCApp.php

```
<form action="post-method.php" method="POST">

<input type="text" name="texta" placeholder="Text to Query" multiple />

<input type="submit" name="submit" />

</form>
```

---

### File 2 - Postmethod.php

```
<?php

    $wtext= ($_POST['texta']);
    //echo $wtext;

    $url = "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/classifiers/{My Classifier ID}/classify?text=$wtext";

    $headers = array('Content-Type:application/json');

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '{My Classifier Username:My Classifier Password}');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_args));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($result === FALSE) {die('Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch)); }
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $result;

?>
```

---

I Suck at coding and most of these small piece of code is copy pasted from multiple user posts in stackoverflow and other help forums.

Any help on completing this pls.

Comment: You set headers telling you are sending JSON. Perhaps remove that?

Comment: Try adding this before the die:
`$result = curl_exec ($ch);
$errors = curl_error($ch);
$response = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($result);
var_dump($errors);
var_dump($response);`

Comment: @mplungan I tried removing the json line produces                          
Warning: curl_setopt(): You must pass either an object or an array with the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\zscripts\post-method.php on line 14

Comment: You of course need to ALSO remove `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);` or comment it out

Comment: adding those lines before die prints the result twice with 1 word and prints following with multiple words - string(0) "" string(0) "" int(505)

Comment: I did comment setopt but no luck

Comment: I think you need to re-encode the text using urlencode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

1. `$ch = curl_init($url);`
2. remove unused headers
3. add error handling

---

```
<?php

$wtext= ($_POST['texta']);
echo "Passed text: ".$wtext; 

$url  = "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/classifiers/{My Classifier ID}/classify?text=";
$url .= urlencode($wtext);

// $headers = array('Content-Type:application/json');

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '{My Classifier Username:My Classifier Password}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_args));

$result = curl_exec ($ch);
// also get the error and response code
$errors = curl_error($ch);
$response = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);

var_dump($result);
var_dump($errors);
var_dump($response);

?>
```

Comment: The entire sentence are now getting passed but the url is not being queried with the input words.Here is the response for word1 word2 word3 input.Passed text: word1 word2 word3string(0) "" string(0) "" int(505)

Comment: U mean like adding a + between all the words? Just tried and it worx. But then I'll need to include code to url encode the entire thing ryt?and the input im gonna need will be in arabic and Im afraid its gonna be problamatic ?

Comment: Added code $enctext=urlencode($wtext);

$url = "https://........../myclassifier/classify?text=$enctext"; Now working fine. Even with Arabic. Thanks boss. You made my day

Comment: Now Im gonna try to catch the json response and list it in a tabled or numbered way. Time to learn more. Thanks for your time sir